# How I can remove "they" and "we" form stop word of nltk.corpus?

Tags: python, nltk

I know that I can update the stop word set by adding to it, but How can I remove from it some stop words I need them in my analysis is there any way to do that using python?

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
print("stop_words :",stop_words)
stop_words_none = stop_words.remove("they")
print("stop_words without they: ",stop_words_none)
```

but the output is :

```
stop_words ['i', 'me', 'my', 'myself', 'we', 'our', 'ours', 'ourselves', 'you', "you're", "you've", "you'll", "you'd", 'your', 'yours', 'yourself', 'yourselves', 'he', 'him', 'his', 'himself', 'she', "she's", 'her', 'hers', 'herself', 'it', "it's", 'its', 'itself', 'they', 'them', 'their', 'theirs', 'themselves', 'what', 'which', 'who', 'whom', 'this', 'that', "that'll", 'these', 'those', 'am', 'is', 'are', 'was', 'were', 'be', 'been', 'being', 'have', 'has', 'had', 'having', 'do', 'does', 'did', 'doing', 'a', 'an', 'the', 'and', 'but', 'if', 'or', 'because', 'as', 'until', 'while', 'of', 'at', 'by', 'for', 'with', 'about', 'against', 'between', 'into', 'through', 'during', 'before', 'after', 'above', 'below', 'to', 'from', 'up', 'down', 'in', 'out', 'on', 'off', 'over', 'under', 'again', 'further', 'then', 'once', 'here', 'there', 'when', 'where', 'why', 'how', 'all', 'any', 'both', 'each', 'few', 'more', 'most', 'other', 'some', 'such', 'no', 'nor', 'not', 'only', 'own', 'same', 'so', 'than', 'too', 'very', 's', 't', 'can', 'will', 'just', 'don', "don't", 'should', "should've", 'now', 'd', 'll', 'm', 'o', 're', 've', 'y', 'ain', 'aren', "aren't", 'couldn', "couldn't", 'didn', "didn't", 'doesn', "doesn't", 'hadn', "hadn't", 'hasn', "hasn't", 'haven', "haven't", 'isn', "isn't", 'ma', 'mightn', "mightn't", 'mustn', "mustn't", 'needn', "needn't", 'shan', "shan't", 'shouldn', "shouldn't", 'wasn', "wasn't", 'weren', "weren't", 'won', "won't", 'wouldn', "wouldn't"]
stop_words without they: None
```

Comment: What did you try, some examples of input and expeced output? it will bu much easier to help you :)

Comment: stopwords is a list so you can just remove them with something like `stopwords.remove("they")` and `stopwords.remove("we")`

Comment: What I want is to keep the "they", "we" in the sentence after using stop words to remove stopwords of nltk.corpus, example: "they search the output for extra data", I want to keep "they" not remove it after using stopwords for removing, I want the output like this "they search output extra data". I hope it is clear now, I will try mr.Plpp comment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list in python is a mutable object, as stated [here](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747):

> mutable object can be changed after it is created, and an immutable object can't. Objects of built-in types like (int, float, bool, str, tuple, unicode) are immutable. Objects of built-in types like (list, set, dict) are mutable.

The python list remove() method does not create a new list, it modifies the list given as argument, see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_remove.htm):

> Python list method remove() searches for the given element in the list and removes the first matching element.
>
> **Return Value**: This Python list method does not return any value but removes the given object from the list.

The following code shows that the word 'they' is indeed removed from the list:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

print('they' in stop_words)
#True
stop_words.remove("they")
print('they' in stop_words)
#False
```